# Structs and enumerations with not-exactly-integral type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enums

Now I am aware of how the following works:

```
template<std::uint8_t num>
struct factorial 
{
    static_assert(num <= 20, "Integer overflow!!");
    enum { value = num * factorial<num - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct factorial<0> 
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};
```

It computes the factorial of a number using recursion at compile time!

You would call this function like so: `std::cout << factorial<20>::value;`

Beautiful, but an `enum` can only hold integral types (up to `std::uintmax_t`). That means we cannot compute the factorial of a number greater than 20.

Now I have written a nice little `bigint` class, which removes the boundaries.

Consider the following:

```
template<std::uintmax_t num>
struct factorial
{
    static bigint value()
    {
        bigint result("1");

        for (bigint i("2"); i <= num; ++i)
            result *= i;

        return result;
    }
};
```

This would need me to call it like so: `std::cout << factorial<99>::value();`. Obviously... since it's a function.

My question is: is there a way to modify the code/function so it would be called like the first example, but still make use of the `bigint` class, which I can't stick in an `enum`.

Comment: For your example, and with c++14, I think just `constexpr` will be enough. Provided that your `bigint` is capable of compile-time calculations.

Comment: You're still limited by the recursion depth of the templates.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, only if he actually _uses_ recursion in templates...

Comment: _"is there a way to modify the code/function so it would be called like the first example, but still make use of the bigint class, which I can't stick in an enum."_ yes, use a bigint not an enum, obviously! Nothing about the original example can't be done with an enum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, with c++14, you can turn your `value()` into a `constexpr`:

```
template<std::uintmax_t num>
struct factorial
{
    constexpr bigint value()
    {
        bigint result(1);
        for (bigint i(2); i <= num; ++i)
            result *= i;
        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(factorial<3>().value() == 6, "");
}
```

Now if you want to have it accessed by old syntax, you can do it easily with

```
template<std::uintmax_t num>
struct factorial
{
    constexpr static bigint calc_value()
    {
        bigint result(1);
        for (bigint i(2); i <= num; ++i)
            result *= i;
        return result;
    }

    constexpr static bigint value = calc_value();
};

...
static_assert(factorial<3>::value == 6, "");
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c46865e51ae2f696) with `bigint` being `unsigned` for the sake of example.

---

Note, however, this places a big requirement on your `bigint` class, that is, it should be able to do all needed calculations at compile time, and this might be much more difficult. However, this is obviously an inherent requirement of your problem.

---

**UPD**: just noticed that your actual question does in fact *not* ask about compile-time calculations, just about `enum`-like syntax. But then it is even easier to do:

```
template<std::uintmax_t num>
struct factorial
{
    static bigint calc_value()  { /* same code */  }
    static const bigint value;
};

template<std::uintmax_t num>
const bigint factorial<num>::value = factorial<num>::calc_value();
```

This is even c++03 compatible if you would use `int` (or similar) instead of `std::uintmax_t`.

Comment: Actually, I'd think it would be generally desirable for a class like `bigint` to support `constexpr` operations, even outside this somewhat artificial problem: the operations are bound to be non-trivial and hoisting constant evaluation to compile-time may make compiling code [more fun](https://xkcd.com/303/) at the benefit of faster programs. To that end, `bigint` would probably involve a size template parameter to avoid the need for memory allocation.

Comment: @DietmarKühl, sure, but most of your arguments apply to a string class, and yet `std::string` does not support `constexpr`... I'd say that designing a `constexpr`-supportive `bigint` is much more difficult than designing a simple `bigint`, so it is a question of a tradeoff.

Comment: Compared to `bigint` multiplication or even more so division `std::string` operations are trivial. I don't think that the `constexpr` version of `bigint` functions would be harder themselves (but I haven't tried implementing them). The primary obstacle is the inability to allocate dynamic memory. It may very well be a case for implementing the operations as algorithms and use them with a size-independent `bigint` (using allocation and not supporting `constexpr`) and a `cbigint<N>` taking the representation size into account.